# Is any homomorphism between two isomorphic fields an isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Is  any  homomorphism  between  two  isomorphic  fields  an  isomorphism?
What  I  mean is  that  two  fields  are  called  isomorphic  if  there  exist one  homomorphism  between  them .  But  not  sure  if  existence  of  one  isomorphism  means  there  exist  no  non-bijective  homomorphism  between .  An  explanation  or  a  counter example  would help . Please.

Answer (score 7):

> What I mean is that two fields are called isomorphic if there exist one homomorphism between them

You mean if there exists an isomorphism between them. It is not true that a homomorphism between two isomorphic fields needs to be an isomorphism. For example, the natural inclusion $\mathbb{C} \to \overline{ \mathbb{C}(t) }$ is not an isomorphism, but the two fields in question are isomorphic. Perhaps a simpler example is the inclusion $\mathbb{C}(x_2, x_3, x_4, ...) \to \mathbb{C}(x_1, x_2, x_3, ...)$.

Answer (score 5):

A homomorphism from one field into another is always one-to-one.  It need not be onto.  But I suspect your "between them" is assumed to imply that it is onto.

Comment: I don’t understand the downvote here; the answer is terse and lacks a concrete example, but it contains the essential information.